# How to pull the newest data from google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a google sheet that is linked to a google form and as soon as the sheet gets a new piece data in column B i want it to be used to send an email.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an onEdit trigger to do this. Inside of the script editor where your email script is, click on the 'clock' icon under 'Publish'. You can set up a trigger for your function here. This link will take you to Google's documentation on triggers.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/

Comment: What im planning to achieve is somthing like this, `code` function onEdit(e){
  // Set a comment on the edited cell to indicate when it was changed.
  var range = e.range;
  range.setNote('Last modified: ' + new Date());
}   `code` But have it put the data in that cell in to a variable